# Streamlining Enum Type Identification with PostgreSQL Comments in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, enums, datagrip

I'm using Ruby on Rails and currently facing a challenge when trying to discern the meaning of numeric values representing enum types within a PostgreSQL column. To illustrate, I have a stage column containing values like {0: removed, 1: live, 2: suspended, 3: enqueued, ...}, and I'm seeking a method to easily identify these associations within a database IDE like Datagrip.

Is there a way to automatically generate PostgreSQL comments for this purpose?

Answer (score -1):

You can use migrations to add comments. For example

```rb
class AddCommentsToStatusColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def up
    comment_text = <<-SQL
      COMMENT ON COLUMN jobs.status IS 
      'Enum: 0 => removed, 1 => live, 2 => suspended, 3 => enqueued';
    SQL

    execute(comment_text)
  end

  def down
    execute("COMMENT ON COLUMN jobs.status IS NULL;")
  end
end
```

Or if you want to automate this for multiple enums, you could use a rake task. You can modify this to work with multiple models. That way, every time you update your enums, you can re-run this rake task to update the comments accordingly.

```rb
namespace :db do
  desc "Add enum comments"
  task enum_comments: :environment do
    comment_text = Job.defined_enums.map do |name, values|
      value_mappings = values.map { |k, v| "#{v} => #{k}" }.join(", ")
      <<-SQL
        COMMENT ON COLUMN jobs.#{name} IS 'Enum: #{value_mappings}';
      SQL
    end.join("\n")

    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(comment_text)
  end
end
```

There are two downsides to the rake task.

1. Not version-controlled in the same way migrations are
2. You have to remember to run it

And migrations have their own downsides.

1. Might be overkill for something like adding a comment
2. Each change requires a new migration file

---

**My original wrong answer:**

If you have an integer column in your table, for example, `status`. Then you can write an enum like this

Option 1:

```rb
enum status: { removed: 0, live: 1, suspended: 2, enqueued: 3 }
```

Option 2:

```rb
enum status: [:removed, :live, :suspended, :enqueued]
```

Comment: The question is about [PostgreSQL comments](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-comment.html) not how to define an Enum in ActiveRecord.